# What is a simple explanation of a context manager with subprocess in Python?

Tags: python

I'm an active python user and it seems most tutorials on the internet point me to a context manager with a subprocess to handle executing binaries through python, for example reading image exif data with exiftool.

```
def readExif(fname):
    with ExifTool() as e:
        try:
            metadata = e.get_metadata(fname)
            metadata = metadata[0]
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
             return False

for f in files:
    print readExif(f)
```

Here's my question (from a real beginner point of view): why can't I just use os.system()?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example (with code) of what you're talking about? There's reasons for using the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system`, but I'm not sure how context managers are factoring into your question.

Answer (score 2):

The `ExifTool` decorator just removes **a lot** of the boilerplate and error handling that you'd need to robustly handle calling the exiftool executable directly using something like `os.system()`. Even if you used `subprocess.Popen` directly, which is more high-level than `os.system`, your code would look something like this to be equivalent to what `ExifTool` provides:

```
with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull:
    _process = subprocess.Popen(
        [self.executable, "-stay_open", "True",  "-@", "-",
         "-common_args", "-G", "-n"],
         stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=devnull)
try:
    _process.stdin.write(b"\n".join([filename] + (b"-execute\n",)))
    _process.stdin.flush()
    output = b""
    fd = _process.stdout.fileno()
    sentinel = b"{ready}"
    while not output[-32:].strip().endswith(sentinel):
       output += os.read(fd, block_size)
    metadata = output.strip()[:-len(sentinel)][0]
    metadata = metdata[0]
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    return False
finally:
    _process.stdin.write(b"-stay_open\nFalse\n")
    _process.stdin.flush()
    _process.communicate()
    del _process
```

(This is completely untested and probably won't work. I just quickly looked at the [source](https://github.com/smarnach/pyexiftool/blob/master/exiftool.py) of pyexiftool to throw this together.)

As you can see, there's a whole lot of stuff going on there. The context manager itself handles everything before the `try` block, and the entire `finally` block. If you wanted to use `ExifTool` without using it as a context manager, but have equivalent functionality, it would look like this:

```
e = ExifTool()
e.start()
try:
    metadata = e.get_metadata(fname)
    metadata = metadata[0]
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    return False
finally:
    e.terminate()
```

You can confirm this by looking at `ExifTool.__enter__()` and `ExifTool.__exit__()`, which are the methods that get called when you enter and exit the `with ExifTool() as e:` block, respectively.

There are certainly lots of simple cases where executing a subprocess with `os.system` directly will work just fine (though in general I'd recommend using the `subprocess` module instead). The particular examples you've been looking at just happen to be a lot more complicated, though, and benefit from the abstractions provided by object-oriented programming and context managers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to accomplish in the child process. os.system() is fine for executing something you don't need to interact with, but often times you need or want to be able to read stdout/stderr and run the subprocess in parallel with the main one. Using a context manager is much more flexible and capable for everything beyond simple subcommand execution.

Comment: You should always use calls from subprocess, it also provides 'simple' interfaces (e.g. call or check) and that way you always use a consistent module for process management.